# Break down $\frac{3x+5}{x^{3}-8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Break down this:
$\frac{3x+5}{x^{3}-8}$
into smaller fractions. (Don't know what the operation is called in english).

My answer is:

$\frac{3x+5}{x^{3}-8}=\frac{\frac{11}{4}}{x-2}+\frac{-\frac{11}{4}+3}{x^{2}-2x+4}$

And here is my [calculation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3y3cqjue0ehtmph/2013-10-08%2015.59.47.jpg)

But I'm wrong according to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B3x%2B5%7D%7Bx%5E%7B3%7D-8%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B4%7D%7D%7Bx-2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B-%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B4%7D%2B3%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D-2x%2B4%7D)

Comment: $x^3 - 8 = (x-2)(x^2 \mathbin{\pmb+} 2x + 4)$

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283x%2B5%29%2F%28x^3-8%29) gives $\frac{-11 x-8}{12 (x^2+2 x+4)}+\frac{11}{12 (x-2)}$

Comment: The + sign solved it. Now I get it right. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B3x%2B5%7D%7Bx%5E%7B3%7D-8%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B12%7D%7D%7Bx-2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B-%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B12%7Dx-%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2B2x%2B4%7D&dataset=&equal=Submit)

Comment: @jacob You should write an answer with your calculations and accept it.

Comment: @martini what do you mean?

Comment: @jacob You should write an answer to your question, with your calculations, and accept it.